# Implement append operation for linked list in dafny with O(1) complexity

Tags: dafny, formal-verification

In dafny, we can use a `set<T>` as the dynamic frame to verify the termination of a linked list:

```c
class Node {
  // the sequence of data values stored in a node and its successors.
  ghost var list: seq<Data>;
  // `footprint` is a set consisting of the node and its successors.
  // it is actually the dynamic frame mentioned in the paper.
  ghost var footprint: set<Node>;

  var data: Data;
  var next: Node?;

  // A "Valid" linked list is one without ring. 
  function Valid(): bool
    reads this, footprint
  {
    this in footprint &&
    (next == null ==> list  == [data]) &&
    (next != null ==> next in footprint &&
                      next.footprint <= footprint &&
                      !(this in next.footprint) &&
                      list == [data] + next.list &&
                      next.Valid())
  }
  ...
}
```

(This is the implementation in [Specification and Verification of Object-Oriented Software](http://leino.science/papers/krml190.pdf).)

However, the `footprint` makes it hard to implement the `append` operation. Because when appending a new node to the linked list, we need to update the `footprint` of all the previous nodes. I wonder if it is possible to implement the `append` with O(1) complexity in dafny (except the ghost methods) or we need to remove the `Valid` and use `decreases *`?

Thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

`footprint` is a `ghost` variable, thus only used by the verifier (and `function`s are `ghost` by definition as well). It would not be compiled and executed, so you don't have to take it into account in your (runtime) complexity analysis.